# TypeInitializerException thrown by ReportDocument constructor

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, 32bit-64bit

I have an ASP .NET web application which has references to assemblies from the 32-bit Crystal Reports runtime. (Installed from CRRedist2008_x86.msi)
The server on which it has been deployed has a 64-bit Crystal Reports runtime.
The form containing the CrystalReportViewer throws the following exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM
>   class factory for component with CLSID
>   {5FF57840-5172-4482-9CA3-541C7878AE0F} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005. at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() at
>   [qualifiedFormName]_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

While I realize that making the dev environment identical to the runtime environment would the ideal solution, I was hoping there were some way to resolve this without having to upgrade the development environment.

Would updating the references to Crystal Reports assemblies in web.config on the server work?

Answer (score 0):

- Open windows registry (Regedit.exe)
- Search for 5FF57840-5172-4482-9CA3-541C7878AE0F
- You should find a key, expand it and go to each child nodes until you find the installation path.
- Go to that path (usually C:\Program ...\Business Objects...\bin...)
- Grant full permission for ASP .NET, IIS worker process, Anonymous Web User process accounts

  You should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Since I don't have direct access to the server, I should probably ask the tech team at the hosting agency to do this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't the hosting agency object to grant said permissions on a shared server?

Comment: You are correct about the restricted permission of this approach. Fortunately for us, we encountered this problem on our developer machines, not on our servers. But even if it happens on the server, we have full access because it's an on-premise cloud. Similar questions about permissions and advance server controls were raised in Cloud Azure platform. This is the main difference between creating an Azure Website (which you don't have control over the VM running it) vs. creating an Azure virtual PC with IIS installed.